# Easy way to display a loading screen while downloading and upserting on ASP?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download

I've only seen examples on how to display loading gifs while the page itself loads, and stopping once it's loaded, but I want it to display the loading gif while the code is downloading some XML files, reading them and upserting its content, it does this with button click event.

I'd like for it to display that circle loading gif, and hopefully like 'lock up' the screen, I got this idea it would look great if it somehow grayed out the page and displayed only a the gif on the center over the rest of the page until the process was finished, like the UAC popup window on Windows, but just the image will do for starters.

What's the best approach for this? Thanks!

Comment: First: is this ASP.NET or classic ASP? Second: is the XML parsing done in the background somehow and you see the page in the meanwhile?

Comment: ASP.NET I suppose, I just typed asp in the tag and it changed to asp-classic. And yeah everything is done in the background, so I wanted the screen to popup while it was being done. I think it's called an overlay. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I retagged; The ASP.NET is the second tag that appears when typing "asp". Next question: how can you tell when the background process is starting and when it's finished? Can the background process access the Session object?

Comment: Thanks I'll take note on that. By the way I probably wrote the question wrong, I don't need it to show the advance it makes while loading, I simply need a popup-kind of message that says "Loading" and the overlay. For me the process starts when the first method is called and ends when they're all done. And I'm not using sessions yet. Thanks again.

Comment: The problem is: how can you tell when the background process is finished, from within the page code behind?

Comment: Yeah I see what you're trying to say, how could the program hide the message if it doesn't know when the process it's finished, and yes everything's on code behind.